# Specifying vendor in Corda Enterprise CorDapp

Tags: corda

I am building a CorDapp against Corda Enterprise. I get the following error messaged when I build my CorDapp:

```
CordApp's vendor is "Unknown". Please specify it in "cordapp.info.vendor".
```

How do I specify the CorDapp's vendor?

Answer (score 1):

As of Corda Enterprise V3.1, you can specify the CorDapp's vendor my adding the following closure to your `build.gradle` file:

```
cordapp {
    info {
        name "My CorDapp"
        vendor "My Company"
        version "1.0.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this documented anywhere besides stackoverflow?

Comment: When I try this in my build.gradle using Corda Enterprise 3.1 and Gradle 4.9 to do the build, it doesn't recognize the cordapp keyword. The message is:  Could not find method cordapp() for arguments on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.

Comment: What version of the CorDapp-plug in are you using? From the docs "For CorDapps depending on the cordapp-plugin, version 4.0.25 allows specifying distribution information." http://docs.corda.r3.com/upgrade-notes.html?highlight=vendor

Comment: ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '4.0.25' - We already made the recommended changes to the gradle build script based on the documentation.

Comment: Could it be that I am putting this closure in the wrong place? I have it just before the buildscript section and after the group and version tags.

Comment: I am still having trouble getting this to work with the specified Gradle entry. I made sure to have all the correct plugins available to the repository but get this error. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Corda\simple-cordapps-release-V3\build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'yo'.
> Could not find method cordapp() for arguments [build_9y1rv02u25a74192ytw4dqhs4$_run_closure1@328a0392] on root project 'yo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: I finally got this to work by putting the closure within the jar task as shown below:

Comment: jar { 
        baseName 'simple-cordapp'
        cordapp {
            info {
                name "simple-cordapp"
                vendor "R3"
                version "1.0"
            }
        }
    }